# Jupyter Scala Kernel Missing

Tags: scala, jupyter

I'm running on OS X 10.10.5.  I'm trying to add the Scala Kernel to my Jupyter notebooks.

```
$ jupyter --version
4.0.4

$ conda --version
conda 3.17.0
```

I downloaded jupyter-scala from git, then built Scala 2.11 from sources.

```
$ sbt cli/target

$ ls -l /Users/davidlaxer/jupyter-scala/cli/target/scala-2.11/

total 224

drwxr-xr-x 4 davidlaxer staff 136 Sep 21 12:39 classes
-rw-r--r-- 1 davidlaxer staff 114465 Sep 21 12:39 jupyter-scala-cli_2.11.6-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

$ sudo jupyter kernelspec install scala-2.11/

Password:

[InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec in /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/

David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:target davidlaxer$ jupyter kernelspec list

Available kernels:

ir
julia-0.3
matlab_kernel
python2

$ ls -l /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/
total 224
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel     136 Sep 21 12:39 classes
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  114465 Sep 21 12:39 jupyter-scala-cli_2.11.6-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Why don't I see the scala2.11 kernel?

No Scala!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To install jupyter-scala from sources, you should do something like

```
git clone https://github.com/alexarchambault/jupyter-scala.git
cd jupyter-scala
sbt cli/pack
cli/target/pack/bin/jupyter-scala
```

Then `ipython kernelspec list` should display scala211.

For the Scala 2.10 kernel, check out the scala-2.10.x branch, and do sbt ++2.10.5 cli/pack instead of sbt cli/pack. The kernel name is then scala210. Note that to have both kernels at the same time this way, you should e.g. clone the repo in two different directories.

—

Comment: This does not work for me using 2.10 branch: `.sbt/0.13/staging/d847f633cdf75ae319d6/sbt-pack/sonatype.sbt:1: error: not found: value sonatypeProfileName
sonatypeProfileName := "org.xerial"
^
[error] Type error in expression
`